# How to view pdf from routes in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, laravel-5

Trying to view pdf stored in `/public/assets/others/brochure/jan-2016.pdf` file from `brochure/jan-2016.pdf', 'BrochureController@show');` route in laravel.

But i get error as : `Whoops, looks like something went wrong`

Route Code :

```
Route::get('/brochure/{file}', 'BrochureController@show');
```

And in controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class BrochureController extends Controller
{   
    public function show($filename)
    {       
        $filename = 'jan-2016.pdf';
        $filepath = 'assets/others/brochure/';
        $path = $filepath.$filename;

        return Response::make(file_get_contents($path), 200, [
        'Content-Type' => 'application/pdf',
        'Content-Disposition' => 'inline; '.$filename,
        ]);
    }
}
```

When i try to print file contents only, its capturing the file and display in some odd manner using `file_get_contents($path)`

**Output:** `%PDF-1.4 %���� 1 0 obj <>stream PScript5.dll Version 5.2.2 GVTP January 2016 Dummy content endstream endobj 2 0 obj <> endobj 4 0 obj <> endobj 3 0 obj <> endobj 5 0 obj <>/Rotate 90/Parent 3 0 R/MediaBox[0 0 595 842]/Contents 11 0 R/Type/Page>> endobj 11 0 obj <>stream x��]Ys�u.;����8Ξ��d���z_�'�Z���Iت�� �$����_��oN�L�9=sw@��-...`

That means its picking the file from the exact path. I believe an reader to be specifed to handle this as a third party service, Ex: Adobe pdf reader.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: You said that your route is `Route::get('/view/{event}', 'PdfController@show');` so can you provide your full `show()` method so that I can see how you are using the event variable? Is it being used for the filename perhaps?

Comment: Yes @Joseph, i had changed the names purposefully, but now its exact the same as i have in my project. Please have a look

Answer (score 6):

Consider on example of an offer contract

---

Controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response;

class OfferController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $file = public_path().DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'media'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'offer.pdf';
        $file = File::get($file);
        $response = Response::make($file,200);
        $response->header('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');
        return $response;
    }
}
```

Route:

```
Route::get('/offer','OfferController@index')->name('offer');
```

Profite:

```
https://name.site/offer
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code

```
$filename = 'assets/others/129778.pdf';
$path = storage_path().DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$filename;

return Response::make($path, 200, [
'Content-Type' => 'application/pdf',
'Content-Disposition' => 'inline; '.$filename,
]);
```

See if it works and do lemme know.

Comment: i saw this answer from other post as well. can u elaborate with `storage_path()` and `directory_separator` there

Comment: Are u sure, the path you have specified is correct ?

Comment: i can access those from url directly like: `http://localhost/laravel/project/public/assets/others/129778.pdf`. But i dont want the end users to see the relative path of the project folder contents. And also it has to get viewed from browsers default pdf viewer.

Comment: You need to add the whole URL. It's not possible without specifying the URL

Comment: if i want to deploy this project online, then i have to change all localhost to domain names as per your suggestion? But thats bad idea, i need to get it from relative path directory :(

Comment: No. Don't add localhost. Just start your URL from /laravel/projects... Or from the directory, where your Php script resides.

Comment: no M.S.P, if it works. ill vote up and accept the answer as well

Answer (score 0):

**In BrochureController.php**

```
public function show($filename)
{
    $file = base_path(). "/public/assets/others/brochure/". $filename;

    $name = "Human Name For File.pdf";

    $headers = ['Content-Type: application/pdf'];

    return Response::download($file, $name, $headers);
}
```

Now access `http://example.com/brochure/jan-2016.pdf` in your app and the jan-2016.pdf file will download.

If you don't want the users to be able to guess that they can also access `http://example.com/assets/others/jan-2016.pdf` then you can move the PDF to another directory (such as `/resources/brochures`) where it is not publicly accessible and then you can just change the first line of the method to:

`$file = base_path(). "/resources/brochures/". $filename;`

This will mean that everyone has to go to `http://example.com/brochure/jan-2016.pdf` to access the file.

Comment: No luck @Joseph, its not downloading as well. I still receive the same error :( `Whoops, looks like something went wrong`. I am thinking whether i need to change any configuration settings in my laravel or apache for this...

Comment: I doubt it's a configuration issue unless you have changed something. It should work out of the box. Can you post the full error and not just the "whoops" part?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this package [barryvdh/laravel-dompdf][1]. and use simply as below:
This is just the example snippset

```
class BrochureController extends Controller
{   
    public function show($filename)
    {       
        $html = 'Your content in PDF';    

        $pdf = PDF::loadHTML($html);

        //set the name of the pdf document
        $file_name = 'jan-2016.pdf';

        //check if the path exist or not
        if(!File::exists(storage_path() . '/pdf')) {

             $result = File::makeDirectory(storage_path() . '/pdf');
        }

        $pdf->save(storage_path() . '/pdf/' . $file_name);

        //return $file_name;

        return $pdf->download($file_name);

    }
}
```